# Logarithmic equation. Need to know if i am teaching right

Tags: logarithms

Two of my friends is studying for a test. They asked me about a simple question. But they told me that i was wrong on a question. I could be wrong. But i need you guys to make sure that they learn the right stuff. So if i was right. I then can tell them how to do the equations

The question:
Assume that $\log x = 3$ and $\log y = 4$
Calculate the following equation $\log x^4 + 2\log y - \log(xy)$

I got it to be

$$\log \left( \frac{x^4  y^2}{x y} \right)$$

Then they just change the $x$ and $y$ to the assumed value.
So am i right or am i wrong

Comment: But you don't know what $x$ and $y$ are - the point is to write everything in terms of $\log{x}$ and $\log{y}$.

Comment: You need to put it into an equation *only* using $\log x$ and $\log y$. So not using, for example, $\log xy$.

Comment: I love the intro. People always complain about people asking questions without giving context. I'm not sure anymore, if I really want the context. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But they aren’t given the values of $x$ and $y$: they’re given the values of $\lg x$ and $\lg y$. Specifically, $\lg x=3$ and $\lg y=4$, so

$$\lg x^4+2\lg y-\lg(xy)=4\lg x+2\lg y-(\lg x+\lg y)=12+8-7=13\;.$$

It’s perfectly true that

$$\lg x^4+2\lg y-\lg(xy)=\lg\frac{x^4y^2}{xy}\;,$$

but this does not really help them to solve the problem.

Comment: Unless they figure out our well-kept secret of how to find $x$ from $\log x$ ;-)

Comment: @fgp: Since the base of the logs isn’t given, that involves considerably more work than it’s worth!

Answer (score 0):

You're right. For logarithms in general it holds that $log(a)+log(b)=log(ab)$ and $log(a)-log(b)=log(a/b)$. Furthermore it holds that $alog(b)=log(b^a)$. Hence, your answer is correct.

Comment: Jemil has correctly combined the expression into a single log, but that does not help in answering the actual question.

Comment: The working is correct, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I assumed that Jemil only wanted to know whether his working was correct. Indeed you are right though that it does not help in answering the question.